# Searching a name using binary search and multiple methods in Java

Tags: java, search

I have created a program that reads in students and 3 test grades from a text file, then allows the user to edit the test grades, sort the students, etc. I need to make a search method using binary search, but I try searching students and they don't come up. I don't have a great grasp on the compareTo() method, but I swear this should work. This is the main method that asks for the name then calls the search method.

```
if (command == 3){
              System.out.println("Enter name of student: ");
              Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(System.in);
              String target = reader1.next();
              if (model.search(target) == -1) {
                System.out.println("No student found with that name");
              }else{
                System.out.println("Student found");
              }
```

This is the search method:

```
public int search(String target) {
  int left = 0;
  int right = studentCount - 1;
  while (left <= right) {
    int midpoint = (left + right) / 2;
    if (students[midpoint].getName().compareTo(target) == 0) {
        System.out.println(students[midpoint]);
        return midpoint;
    }else{
      if (students[midpoint].getName().compareTo(target) > 1) {
        left = midpoint + 1;
      }else{
        right = midpoint - 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

And I don't know if you need this, but this is the getName() method:

```
public String getName (){
  return name2 + " " + name;
}
```

And finally this is the text file:

Tom Jones 80 90 80

Mary Smith 50 60 90

Hillary Jones 100 54 98

Sammy Alba 98 87 76

Zitti Kambos 76 56 98

Tim Zulla 87 67 87

Beth Babson 98 78 87

Jim zone 56 76 78

Addy Crocker 98 87 87

Matt Brooks 56 76 78

I usually try searching "Jones Tom","JonesTom","TomJones", and "Tom Jones" and none of them come up. Any ideas?

Comment: It’s worth looking at the actual `students` array’s content rather than the text file. Are you aware of the fact that binary search requires a *sorted* array as its input?

Comment: I was not aware of that. and the `students` array is actually an array of objects if that changes anything

Comment: And i just tried sorting it then searching and that did not work

Comment: “that did not work” is not a satisfying problem description. How did you sort that array? You have to sort it using the same criteria than your search. This implies that when you search for a particular `getName()` result you have to sort the array by the `getName()` values.